# Custom rotatable value from inputbox to jQuery .rotatable event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Developing a Customizable product integration, I had an event trigger option to rotate a Div element using jQuery .rotatable handle, that is working good. Event triggered by *.ui-rotatable-handle*

But I need to control the same rotate angles using Inputbox values, that is when user typed any values, it affects dynamically to bind the .rotatable event using jQuery.

```
jQuery('.class').rotatable({ containment: "parent",
    wheelRotate: false,             
    stop: function(event, ui) {                 

        if(ui.angle.current<0){
            var given_angle = ui.angle.current+2*Math.PI;
        }else{
            var given_angle = ui.angle.current;
        }

        var new_angle = Math.round(given_angle*180/ Math.PI);
        if(new_angle){
            jQuery('#rotate_s').val(new_angle);
        }
    }
});
```

Html Inputbox to custom trigger

```
jQuery('#rotate_s').keyup(function() {

        var rotate_u = jQuery(this).val();

 _//Required some code to reflect the existing rotatable event_

});
```

Inputbox

```
 <input type="text" name="rotate_s" id="rotate_s" value="0">
```

Comment: Pls post some code to show what you have done so far..

Comment: So when the value of an inputbox changes, the box should rotate?

Make use of onchange.

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao, Hope you my question, I have updated my code.

Comment: @ ThomasV, when user enters updating any values in the textbox, then it needs to change...onchange/keyup

Answer (score 0):

Notice changes on your inputfield, and add a class to this element.

```
$( ".inputfield" ).change(function() {
  $(this).addClass('rotatable');
});
```

Of course the class rotatable should have some transition and transform css code to rotate the div.